# .framework files on osx build configuration

Tags: c++, macos

I have a .framework file which was built using some c++ standard. Is there any way to find out which c++ standard was used to build them? (Like c++11 or earlier).

I have tried the `otool` command but it doesn't work. Is there any way to do it?

For reference: [What exactly is a Framework in Mac OS X? ( *.framework folders )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618027/what-exactly-is-a-framework-in-mac-os-x-framework-folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'oTool' command does not run on `.framework` file but it runs on the executable file inside the `.framework`.

So, passing the `-L` flag prints the shared libraries used in the `.framework`.

`oTool -L filePath`
 will return a list of libraries, one of them will be `libc++` or `libstdc++` depending on the C++ version used.