# Python script shows different pythonpath

Tags: python, path, wxpython, pythonpath

Attempting to run [runsnake](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/) gives

```
ImportError: No module named wx
```

Opening an ipython or python session seems to work fine:

```
>>> import wx
>>> import sys
>>> print [p for p in sys.path if 'wx' in p]    
['/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.4-osx_cocoa', '/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.1-osx_cocoa/tools']
```

as does putting that code in a script and calling `python script.py`. But putting that code at the beginning of `runsnake.py` prints an empty list (printing the whole `sys.path` prints a path quite different from my $PYTHONPATH).

Why would it be different, and how to I get it to recognize wxPython?

Edit: `pip freeze` output contains

```
SquareMap==1.0.1
RunSnakeRun==2.0.2b1
wxPython==2.9.4.0
wxPython-common==2.9.4.0
```

Comment: Can you please detail _how_ you installed runsnake?

Comment: do you mean `pip freeze` shows both `RunSnakeRun` and `wxPython==2.9.4.0` and `wxPython-common==2.9.4.0`?

Comment: I kind of fixed it by manually running `sys.path.extend(['wx directories...'])`. That got rid of the `import wx` problem, now I have what looks like an unrelated error along the lines of "Please run with a Framework build of python...".

Comment: what is sys.executable in/outside runsnake?

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin/python in both cases (homebrew python)

Comment: note: PYTHONPATH environment variable adds directories to sys.path e.g., mine is unset as a rule. Are there `-S` option in the runsnake shebang? What sys.path looks like in `/usr/local/Cellar/.../python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'`?

Comment: The top line of the file was `#! /usr/bin/env python`, so no `-S` option. And when I do the `/usr/...' command you suggested, it includes the wx directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Are you running `runsnake.py` and the python interpreter in the same `virtualenv`? If not you will not have the same packages.
- If you are running `runsnake.py` in a virtual environment constructed with `--no-site-packages`, you will not have access to system-wide packages. Running `pip freeze` will tell you if you have access to `wxPython`. If you don't then that's the issue. You can create a new `virtualenv` properly.
- Did you install wxPython before or after you run the `virtualenv` command?
- Check the shebang, to see if it is running the same python `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`
- you can also try to force which interpreter to use with `python runsnake.py`

For Framework build of python on OSX, [please see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444543/differences-between-framework-and-non-framework-builds-of-python-on-mac-os-x).

Comment: I'm not running it in a virtualenv, but the output of `pip freeze` contains `wxPython==2.9.4.0; wxPython-common==2.9.4.0`

Comment: I got it working with your last suggestion, though it's pretty tedious: `/usr/bin/pythonw2.7 /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/runsnakerun/runsnake.py <filename>`. I thought I could just put `#! /usr/bin/pythonw2.7` in the first line to get it working, but apparently not. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try running runsnake outside of a virtualenv.

See detailed reasons here:  http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonVirtualenvOnMac