# Pip3 didn't install a user-scoped package to ~/.local/bin

Tags: python, macos, pip

I recently installed `pipenv` using the following command: `pip3 install --user pipenv`. (It's also worth mentioning that I'm following Python's official guide [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).) Most online resources seem to indicate that the default installation directory for user-scoped packages is at `~/.local/bin`. However, it would seem that my installation of `pipenv` resides in `~/Library/Python/3.6/bin`. I'm concerned that keeping the installation in a version specific directory (i.e. Python 3.6) could lead to problems down the road. What happened? Should I be worried?

Comment: So what does `python3 -m site` say the `USER_SITE` location is?

Comment: And keeping things installed *per Python version* is absolutely the right choice to make.

Comment: @GhostlyMartijn `python3 -m site` is what originally led me to `~/Library/Python/3.6/bin`. It returns `~/Library/Python/3.6/bin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely correct behaviour, and not something that you need to worry about.

Python packages with native compiled extensions are tied to the specific Python version into which it is installed and should not be shared. Because you can't detect a-priori what package will contain native extensions, **all** Python packages are installed in a version-specific location.

The `--user` switch installs in the [*User Scheme* location](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs):

> With Python 2.6 came the ["user scheme" for installation](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme), which means that all Python distributions support an alternative install location that is specific to a user. The default location for each OS is explained in the python documentation for the [`site.USER_BASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE) variable. This mode of installation can be turned on by specifying the [`--user`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-user) option to `pip install`.

You can always list your `USER_BASE` location by running:

```
python3 -m site
```

(using the same Python binary as tied to your `pip` command).

The Python module search path automatically includes the user location, and because that location is Python version (major.minor) specific, won't interfere with other Python versions.

`~/Library/Python/3.6/` is the *Mac OS X* specific path used when you have a [framework build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444543/differences-between-framework-and-non-framework-builds-of-python-on-mac-os-x). You can override the path by setting the [`PYTHONUSERBASE` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUSERBASE).